# get_terms filter causes category list checkbox to be unchecked

Tags: wordpress

I have code that sorts categories to display on the wordpress admin.    It takes a list of allowed category IDs and returns a list of categories that include those ids.    That part works great except that in the categories list on the edit post page no categories attached to that post get checked (yet they display on the post list page).  What is happening?  It works well everywhere else in the admin apart from that one issue ;(

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'terms_filter', 10, 2);
function terms_filter($terms, $taxes) {
$filteredTerms = [];
if($taxes[0] === "category" || $taxes[0] === "products"){
    global $wpdb;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if($user->exists()){
        $role = $user->roles[0];

        $sql = "    SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}catpermissions.term_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}catpermissions
                    WHERE role = '$role'
                    UNION
                    SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                    ";
        $cats = $wpdb->get_col($sql);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++){
            if(isIn($terms[$i]->term_id, $cats) ){
                //check if parent is in
                if(!isIn($terms[$i]->parent, $cats) ){
                    $terms[$i]->parent = 0;
                }
                $filteredTerms[] = $terms[$i];
            }
        }
    }
    return $filteredTerms;
}

//check for orphans 
for($i = 0; $i < count($terms); $i++){
    //check if parent is in
    if(!isIn($terms[$i]->parent, $terms) ){
        $terms[$i]->parent = 0;
    }
    $filteredTerms[] = $terms[$i];
}

  return $filteredTerms;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you may set the condition on it that if post field value is equal to selected checkbox value of that post field  , it will be checked. else empty.

Comment: @Techno Deviser there is no such value, nothing to mark as checked.